# How to solve HttpException in CheckForMaintenanceMode trying to access invalid file path?

Tags: php, symfony, exception, laravel-5, sandbox

I'm receiving this exception report from my application but I cannot identify how is this being generated.

I can see that there is a strange file access `/var/www/http://...`, just makes no sense. But I cannot find how does it build this path.

The exception dump as follows

```
exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException' in /var/www/http://sandbox4b5acedf8a89cd3fe18ca87e7f5030a4.mailgun.org/c/eJxNj82OgzAMhJ8GjigJLIRDDqtKaPfAQxjblKj5QWlKX3_d214830gej0zOmnHQrXd6IzOxNf2GBocRxkHt2hLhjKzQ6mZQxDF31Ue-F0-dz-3hDGvYN6153-zcq2k0X3ocCCYyvVIK2-D-BRqzfG6IHJUyPgUuTpSLQIACFwehvUDkdy4P4WdBmb8hvKJPUFnMkl-JoPqcxPzUeoqsnijwG8pn4XYwPpZcVvCpcoKEvGbi7jzOpv_u57Y4kDZ_gfx0j-BDhzn-AV-oVww
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#1 /var/www/http://sandbox4b5acedf8a89cd3fe18ca87e7f5030a4.mailgun.org/c/eJxNjjESgyAQRU-jpQOICAVtZtLlCsiuuhMQB425fjadzf73i_9mwVtltGzJywnUiFb1U1RRm2C0mKUFiC6iiFY2WgDm0p2UcakEHZV29WI0IJ3TvRtmAbMW0sjeOQfDqNhj2-Rvg0Y9_g6O9YQSD4YLNyiVIYUaLkxMcw0Zv6W-mY8a-T5T-mTawolcXrRjou2O3b7ubfWBHXQF_nTJgVIXS_4B5NlIAQ(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 /var/www/http://sandbox4b5acedf8a89cd3fe18ca87e7f5030a4.mailgun.org/c/eJxNjjESgyAQRU-jpQOICAVtZtLlCsiuuhMQB425fjadzf73i_9mwVtltGzJywnUiFb1U1RRm2C0mKUFiC6iiFY2WgDm0p2UcakEHZV29WI0IJ3TvRtmAbMW0sjeOQfDqNhj2-Rvg0Y9_g6O9YQSD4YLNyiVIYUaLkxMcw0Zv6W-mY8a-T5T-mTawolcXrRjou2O3b7ubfWBHXQF_nTJgVIXS_4B5NlIAQ(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#4 /var/www/http://sandbox4b5acedf8a89cd3fe18ca87e7f5030a4.mailgun.org/c/eJxNjr1uwzAQg58mHg1Jlh150Bq06FOc7k6xUP0YiuK-fq9bF_LjQILkndmsnpLXgcydnVkCGrQbbFZF7YhwR1bo9M0q4tLmkQo_e6I5tenwTkFYFlppCSvvq9q3uId4NyZqYLRuyv5f4WYefxtix6CGL4GLK7UukKHDxVkodij80_q38Kuj6GfO75IqDJbwaO9KMFKrEj7GOMW-uFfO83mcU_cgU-kCOfwskPKMrfwChLxLXQ(122): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#5 /var/www/http://sandbox4b5acedf8a89cd3fe18ca87e7f5030a4.mailgun.org/c/eJxNjr1uwzAQg58mHg1Jlh150Bq06FOc7k6xUP0YiuK-fq9bF_LjQILkndmsnpLXgcydnVkCGrQbbFZF7YhwR1bo9M0q4tLmkQo_e6I5tenwTkFYFlppCSvvq9q3uId4NyZqYLRuyv5f4WYefxtix6CGL4GLK7UukKHDxVkodij80_q38Kuj6GfO75IqDJbwaO9KMFKrEj7GOMW-uFfO83mcU_cgU-kCOfwskPKMrfwChLxLXQ(87): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 /var/www/http://sandbox4b5acedf8a89cd3fe18ca87e7f5030a4.mailgun.org/c/eJxNjTESwyAMBF9jSsbIWCEFbf4hJGxrBoLHsTN5fkiXarfZO4kB0Duj0SWBWw4wJQb2SOjHxQURvnMeObjBj5Jrs6fWvB4qVpvZIsmScCaYHdCMgCAyZfQ4ESWXUEyJf8EAj99Gx3ZK41eX_UpFuYs-JX_svu3miFTo0Df1y7WSFsutfgHnsDWk(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 {main}
```

[Sharing codebase](https://github.com/timegridio/timegrid)